# Android - linebreak-behavior on textview

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

got a problem with how the linebreak behaves in android

It's breaking like this([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHdyV.png)):

```
Text View 1 | Text View 2 with linebreak
            | is breaking like this
```

I want it to break like this:

```
Text View 1 | Text View 2 with linebreak
breaks like this
```

Here's my xml:

```
<LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent">

       <TextView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="New Text "
               android:id="@+id/textView2"
               android:textColor="#000000"
               android:singleLine="true"/>

        <TextView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="New TextNew TextNew TextNew TextNew TextNew Text"
               android:id="@+id/textView3"
               android:singleLine="false"
               android:phoneNumber="false"
               android:textColor="#000000"
               android:textStyle="bold|italic"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

is this possible, if so how?

Comment: This is not possible, may be you can try show it in a single `TextView`, if you desire to do.

Comment: I can't do that sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with two separate `TextViews` since they don't have the ability to flow around one another.  They are just boxes that contain text.

Comment: So there's no way to make it work? Because I can't put everything in one textView.

Comment: Not in two `TextView`s.  Your only choice would be to use one `TextView` and format it. http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/08/easy-method-for-formatting-android.html

Comment: I ended up putting it in one TextView, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It is unfortunately not possible using the layout approach you have followed.

Possible solution could be to use Html.fromHtml(...) in TextView's SetText method as below:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("this is sample<b><i>text for this textview. Android - linebreak-behavior on textview<i></b>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to put the second text view over the first one and then add some whitespace in front of the text in the second text view.